# Dado el hash() de Python, ¿existe similar en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, python, python-2.7, hash

Tengo un script de python, que realiza un login y pass, el que se almacena con hash en Mysql, con el siguiente código:

```
pass = hash(self.get_argument("psw", 'dato'))
```

generando un hash tipo **-5995266028892256335**

Ahora necesito realizar un login desde PHP, tengo entendido que existe la función hash en php:

```
echo hash('md5', 'mipass');
```

pero no logro determinar en qué formato lo esta generando Python.

Comment: Si no me equivoco en python deberías de estar utilizando `hashlib`,  'hash' no está pensado para eso si no me equivoco, puedes ver unos ejemplos aquí https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-backpack/wiki/How-to-hash-&-salt-in-various-languages.

Comment: Tocara modificar el código de python :/, gracias por tu respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho necesito logear me a una db de MySQL desde Python y PHP, pero al parecer el método de encriptación de Python no estándar para ser usado también PHP. En definitiva buscaba resolver este problema desde PHP, pero creo que corresponde cambiar el sistema de login en Python.

Comment: Recomendación de seguridad, usa Sha1, Sha256, Sha512 en ves de md5,  por ejemplo tanto en python como php la funcion Sha1 es `sha1()` solo que en python has `hexdigest()`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en Python [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) NO es una rutina criptográfica, simplemente es una rutina interna para devolver un valor entero que funciona como identificador único del objeto. Una misma contraseña en distintas ejecuciones o instancias de Pyhton te dará múltiples `hash`. por ejemplo:

```
c:> python -c "print(hash('hola'))"
c:> 161768099
c:> python -c "print(hash('hola'))"
c:> -339335518
```

Lo que si puedes hacer es usar el módulo [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
import hashlib
hash = hashlib.sha256("contraseña").hexdigest()
print(hash)

> edf9cf90718610ee7de53c0dcc250739239044de9ba115bb0ca6026c3e4958a5
```

La cadena recibida será tu `hash` para salvar en la base de datos. En PHP si existe la rutina [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.hash.php) como criptográfica, la forma de repetir el código anterior sería así:

```
<?php
echo hash('sha256', 'contraseña');
?>

edf9cf90718610ee7de53c0dcc250739239044de9ba115bb0ca6026c3e4958a5
```

#### Importante:

La elección del algoritmo de hash es todo un tema, `md5` es extremadamente fácil y rápido de calcular, por lo que ataques de fuerza bruta son totalmente factibles, te sugiero que apuntes a `sha256` para arriba, generan `hashes` mas largos y más difíciles de resolver por fuerza bruta. De cualquier forma estos algoritmo son de propósitos generales y no fueron diseñados especialmente para resolver contraseñas, si agregamos que el poder computacional sigue creciendo, un `hash` considerado seguro hoy no lo puede ser mañana. Hoy por hoy se suelen recomendar otros algoritmos para tratar las contraseñas, te recomiendo [este documento](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema que devuelva diferentes hashes para `hola` y `Hola` ya que las h\H no son el mismo caracter, lo que si es correcto python usar hexdigest() para que el formato salida sea equivalente.

Comment: Es cierto, @RicardoD.Quiroga, elegí mal el ejemplo, ahora lo edito

Comment: Si igual ahi entendi el problema, que `hash()` esta devolviendo el apuntador de memoria, en ves de la suma

Comment: Exacto, el tema es que cadenas iguales tiene el mismo `id`. Voy a reelaborar el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

No conozco esa función hash(), para crear un hash md5 sería de la siguiente forma:

```
import hashlib
hash = hashlib.md5("contraseña")
```

Saludos

Edito: No obstante para evitar cambiar mucho también se podría crear o modificar esa función hash y usar hashlib dentro, por ejemplo:

```
def hash(texto):
    return hashlib.md5(texto)
```

Edit2:

Es verdad, cómo dice Patricio, pensé en hash como una función definida por el usuario, no es buena idea, y en el código me falto hexdigest:

```
import hashlib
hash = hashlib.md5("contraseña").hexdigest()
```

Muchas gracias.